# js form check and submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

revised question:
upon hitting the subscribe button in my current form, the button label changes to "sending" but does NOT get past that. there are codes in place that should change the label of the button to display "Message Sent." The message, or in this case email and name form submission to my mailchimp account, does in fact get sent, but the user doesn't know it based on the button status. THAT is my problem.

This is my html:

```
<form action="http://sawtoothgroup.us5.list-manage.com/subscribe/post"
    class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6" id="contact-form" method="post" name=
    "contact-form" novalidate="">
        <input name="u" type="hidden" value="34f19b17d46b112e06d8ecccd">
        <input name="id" type="hidden" value="6527c49f30">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="MERGE0">Email</label>

            <div class="controls">
                <input class="form-control input-lg requiredField"
                data-error-empty="Please enter your email" data-error-invalid=
                "Invalid email address" id="MERGE0" name="MERGE0" placeholder=
                "Your email" type="email">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="MERGE1">First Name</label>

            <div class="controls">
                <input class="form-control input-lg requiredField"
                data-error-empty="Please enter your first name" id="MERGE1"
                name="MERGE1" placeholder="First name" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="MERGE2">Last Name</label>

            <div class="controls">
                <input class="form-control input-lg requiredField"
                data-error-empty="Please enter your last name" id="MERGE2"
                name="MERGE2" placeholder="Last name" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>

        <p><button class="btn btn-king btn-block" data-error-message="Error!"
        data-ok-message="Message Sent" data-sending-message="Sending..." name=
        "submit" type="submit"><i class=
        "icon-location-arrow"></i>Subscribe</button></p><input id="submitted"
        name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true">
</form>
```

and this is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact-form').submit(function() {
        var buttonCopy = $('#contact-form button').html(),
            errorMessage = $('#contact-form button').data('error-message'),
            sendingMessage = $('#contact-form button').data('sending-message'),
            okMessage = $('#contact-form button').data('ok-message'),
            hasError = false;
        $('#contact-form .error-message').remove();
        $('#contact-form .requiredField').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('inputError');
            if($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                var errorText = $(this).data('error-empty');
                $(this).parents('.controls').append('<span class="error-message" style="display:none;">'+errorText+'.</span>').find('.error-message').fadeIn('fast');
                $(this).addClass('inputError');
                hasError = true;
            } else if($(this).is("input[type='email']") || $(this).attr('name')==='MERGE0') {
                var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                if(!emailReg.test($.trim($(this).val()))) {
                    var invalidEmail = $(this).data('error-invalid');
                    $(this).parents('.controls').append('<span class="error-message" style="display:none;">'+invalidEmail+'.</span>').find('.error-message').fadeIn('fast');
                    $(this).addClass('inputError');
                    hasError = true;
                }
            }
        });
        if(hasError) {
            $('#contact-form button').html('<i class="fa fa-times"></i>'+errorMessage).addClass('btn-error');

            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#contact-form button').removeClass('btn-error').html(buttonCopy);

            },2000);
        }
        else {
            $('#contact-form button').html('<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin"></i>'+sendingMessage);

            var formInput = $(this).serialize();
            $.post($(this).attr('action'),formInput, function(data){
                $('#contact-form button').html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>'+okMessage);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#contact-form button').html(buttonCopy);
                },2000);

            });
        }
        return false;   
    });
});
```

and this is my css:

```
.contact-item h2{
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:600;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.contact-item .icon{
    display:block;
    font-size:48px;
    color:#5cc9df;
    text-shadow:-2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-out;
    transition:all .3s ease-out;
}
.contact-item .icon:hover{
    color:#5cc9df;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.3) translateY(-10px);
    transform:scale(1.3) translateY(-10px);
}
.bl_form {
    margin: 30px 0 0;
}
.bl_form input {
    padding-top: 15px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.10);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    outline: none;
}
.lb_wrap .lb_label.top, 
.lb_wrap .lb_label.bottom {
    left: 66px !important;
}
.lb_wrap .lb_label.left {
    left: 0;
}
.lb_label {
    font-size:17px;
    line-height:32px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #ccc;
}
.no-placeholder .lb_label {
    display:none;
}
.lb_label.active {
    color: #aaa;
}
#contact-form .form-group label{
    display:none;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:24px;
    font-weight:100;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
#contact-form.no-placeholder .form-group label{
    display:block;
}
#contact-form .controls {
    padding:0;
}
#contact-form.no-placeholder .controls {
    margin-top:0;
}
#contact-form .form-control,
.input-group .form-control {
    display:inline;
    background:#fff;
    border:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    outline:none;
    height:52px;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:32px;
    color:#aaa;
    font-weight:400;
    vertical-align:top;
    border:2px solid #FFF;
    box-shadow:none;
}
#contact-form .form-group.half-width{
    width:40%;
    float:left;
}
#contact-form .btn-king{
    margin: 0;
}
#contact-form .form-group{
    position:relative;
}
#contact-form .form-group [class*=fa] {
    display:block;
    width:64px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:5px;
    color:#eee;
    font-size:24px;
    line-height:52px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:300;
    -webkit-transition:color .3s ease-out;
    transition:color .3s ease-out;
}
#contact-form .form-group [class*=fa].active{
    color:#ccc;
}
#contact-form.no-placeholder .form-group [class*=fa]{
    top:30px;
}
#contact-form textarea.form-control {
    height:auto;
    max-width:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:400;
    line-height:24px;
    padding-top:14px;
    vertical-align:top;
    border:2px solid #FFF;
}
#contact-form .form-control:focus, 
.input-group .form-control:focus {
    outline:none;
    border:2px solid #2AAFC3;
}
#contact-form .inputError,
#contact-form textarea.form-control.inputError,
#newsletter-form .inputError {
    outline:none;
    border:2px solid #F05557;
}

#contact-form .error-message {
    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
    right:12px;
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:24px;
    font-weight:400;
    color:#F05557;
    z-index:10;
}
#contact-form.no-placeholder .error-message {
    top:0;
}
.input-group-btn .btn-king {
    margin: 0;
}
#main-footer,
#social {
    padding: 40px 0 20px;
}
#topcontrol {
    background: #84aac9;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -ms-border-radius: 2px;
    -o-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
#topcontrol:hover {
    background: #6091ba;
}
#topcontrol .fa {
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

please let me know what im doing wrong...

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/154codmr/

Comment: by not working properly, please expand

Comment: yes, make your problem clearer and tell the story of what the specific result to expect, we cannot answer by just guessing

Comment: [link]http://areyouirresistible.com/ @DACrosby form is at the bottom...

Comment: and @DACrosby was that jsfiddle a solution or just organizing my question?